# Website Copyright Laws under Intellectual Property Laws?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property

What are the laws regarding Copyrights pertaining to copying of website templates ( which is an intellectual property )?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there are no specific laws relating to the copyright of web site templates, at least in the United States.

That being the case, to the extent they constitute copyrightable material, exactly the same copyright laws apply to them as would apply to a song, a painting, or a novel.